# RDLC export to pdf - IDAutomation font not embedding in Windows Server 2019

Tags: asp.net, iis, rdlc, windows-server

We have an asp.net application with rdlc, we export pdf from rdlc with IDAutomation fonts(barcode) its working perfectly in windows server 2016, now we migrated to windows server 2019, every thing works well in browser, but IDAutomation fonts are not embedded in exported pdf. Any thing I need to add in windows server 2019.

I checked

1. IIS Mime/Types, its same in 2016 & 2019
2. Untrusted font blocking in group policy, its same in 2016 & 2019

Any suggestion will be greatly helpful

Answer (score 6):

After long search search I found, in Windows Server 2019 during font installation we need to right click on font & install for all users, after that do a restart, now fonts will embed in pdf.

Comment: Thank you Bala! That fixed our issue with Windows 2019 and IDAutomation fonts too!